# Ubuntu 14.04 - External Hard Disk not detected via USB Hub but detected when directly connected

Tags: 14.04, usb, external-hdd

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS through `sudo apt-get upgrade`. However, on restarting my `Xorg` crashed and my system wouldn't boot after the splashscreen. Somehow, I managed to uninstall `Xserver` and reinstalled it and my system booted up into Unity (after facing the login screen loop).
However, from that moment onwards, none of my external hard disks are being detected. When I connect them individually to the USB port, it shows up but not through the hub. I changed cables and tried basic diagnostics such as `dmesg` and `fdisk` and `lsusb` but none of them worked.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

`lsusb` output when hub connected

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 058f:a001 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8086:0189 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0d8c:0126 C-Media Electronics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 046d:c246 Logitech, Inc. Gaming Mouse G300
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0411:0240 BUFFALO INC. (formerly MelCo., Inc.)
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0835:8501 Action Star Enterprise Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0835:8500 Action Star Enterprise Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

As can be seen `Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0411:0240 BUFFALO INC. (formerly MelCo., Inc.)` is the only HDD being detected (I used to have 3 connected, including this).

Individually connected, here are the others:

```
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 0bc2:2332 Seagate RSS LLC
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 04e8:1f06 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd HX-MU064DA portable harddisk
```

Comment: What exactly does `lsusb` show when you connect the drive either directly or through the hub?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Included said output.

Comment: Is `Bus 001 Device 007: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB` the problematic USB hub? Do the drives have their own power supply or do they rely on the USB power supply? In the latter case, the USB hub may not provide enough power for (all) the drives.

Comment: @DavidFoerster They are running on an external _powered_ USB hub.  And the issue isn't with the power. I have been running these drives together for quite some time now, on the same hub. I can't figure out why they stopped working suddenly.

Comment: Is the hub itself OK? Can you e.g. run a keyboard through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. The problem was with the hub itself. There was an issue with the power input jack that gave a not so consistent power supply to the hub, hence disks kept showing on and off.
Fixed that, all working now.